# From a decorator, cleanly access target functions module namespace

Tags: python, namespaces, decorator

I have a set of functions in module X, that all share a set of inputs.  Therefore, I'd like to use string formatting to replace an identifier with a long string.  For this, I am using a decorator, such as,

```
inputs = """Some long string"""
@expanddoc
def spam(...):
    """This is a silly function.

    {inputs}
    :returns: Something useless
    """

@expanddoc
def eggs(...):
    """This is an even sillier function.

    {inputs}
    :returns: Something pointless
    """
```

Where I have the function `expanddoc`, defined in module Y, as,

```
def expanddoc(func):
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.format(**globals()
    return func
```

but `**globals()` refers to `Y`s namespace, as opposed to `X`s namespace.  How do I cleanly access the namespace of whatever module `func` is defined in, from the decorator `expanddoc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I figured out the answer, so I decided to post it right here.  But if someone has a different solution, that is more stable or clean, I'm still interested.

The dictionary to be passed to `.format` should be:

`vars(sys.modules[func.__module__])`

Answer (score 0):

This should behave almost the same:

```
import X
def expanddoc(func):
    func.__doc__ = func.__doc__.format(vars(X))
    return func
```

Comment: But `func` can be coming from any module, it`s not necessarily `X` — I can`t hardcode that in `expanddoc`, because I don`t know that yet.